# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Deno.openPlugin is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, deno

This is my database connection

```
import { MongoClient, Database } from "https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.8.0/mod.ts";

let db: Database;

export function connect() {
  const client = new MongoClient();
  client.connectWithUri(
    "mongodb+srv://mahdi:<password>@cluster0.dzbrnoa.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
  );

  db = client.database("todo-app");
}

export function getDb() {
  return db;
}
```

And this is my route file

```
import { Router } from 'https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts';
import { ObjectId } from 'https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.8.0/mod.ts';

import { getDb } from '../helpers/db_client.ts';

const router = new Router();

interface Todo {
  id?: string;
  text: string;
}

let todos: Todo[] = [];

router.get('/todos', async (ctx) => {
  const todos = await getDb().collection('todos').find(); // { _id: ObjectId(), text: '...' }[]
  const transformedTodos = todos.map(
    (todo: { _id: ObjectId; text: string }) => {
      return { id: todo._id.$oid, text: todo.text };
    }
  );
  ctx.response.body = { todos: transformedTodos };
});

router.post('/todos', async (ctx) => {
  const data = await ctx.request.body().value;
  const newTodo: Todo = {
    // id: new Date().toISOString(),
    text: data.text,
  };

  const id = await getDb().collection('todos').insertOne(newTodo);

  newTodo.id = id.$oid;

  ctx.response.body = { message: 'Created todo!', todo: newTodo };
});

router.put('/todos/:todoId', async (ctx) => {
  const tid = ctx.params.todoId;
  const data = await ctx.request.body().value;
  const todoIndex = todos.findIndex((todo) => {
    return todo.id === tid;
  });
  todos[todoIndex] = { id: todos[todoIndex].id, text: data.text };
  ctx.response.body = { message: 'Updated todo' };
});

router.delete('/todos/:todoId', (ctx) => {
  const tid = ctx.params.todoId;
  todos = todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== tid);
  ctx.response.body = { message: 'Deleted todo' };
});

export default router;
```

When I'm trying to connect to database I get this error <-- Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Deno.openPlugin is not a function
return Deno.openPlugin(localPath); -->
I used --unstable and --allow-plugin but it seems that --unstable is deprecated or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

try using the unsafe flag while running..

```bash
deno run --unstable <file_path>
```